# Store dataframe into json fromat with group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I have DF in below format

| id | type | application | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | spark | 2 |
| 1 | test | kafka | 1 |
| 1 | test1 | spark | 2 |
| 2 | test2 | kafka | 1 |
| 2 | test2 | kafka | 1 |
| 3 | test | spark | 2 |

o/p I am looking for is

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"test":{"spark":2,"kafka":1},"test1":{"spark":2}} |
| 2 | {"test2":{"kafka":1}} |
| 3 | {"test":{"spark":2}} |

I have tried several approaches but nothing returned me expected format

Answer (score 1):

If your input dataframe is not too large, you can loop every unique id, then type, then application in turn as following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [1, "test", "spark", 2],
    [1, "test", "kafka", 1],
    [1, "test1", "spark", 2],
    [2, "test2", "kafka", 1],
    [2, "test2", "kafka", 1],
    [3, "test", "spark", 2],
], columns=['id', 'type', 'application', 'number'])

data = []
for id in df['id'].unique():
    id = int(id)
    subdf1 = df[df['id']==id]
    row = {"id": id, "type": {}}
    for type in subdf1['type'].unique():
        subdf2 = subdf1[subdf1['type']==type]
        row["type"][type] = {}
        for application in subdf2['application'].unique():
            subdf3 = subdf2[subdf2['application']==application]
            # Take the "number" of first row
            # before that, make sure all input rows with same id,type,application have same "number", 
            first_row = subdf3.iloc[0] 
            number = int(first_row['number']) 
            row["type"][type][application] = number
    data.append(row)

out = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   id                                               type
0   1  {'test': {'spark': 2, 'kafka': 1}, 'test1': {'...
1   2                            {'test2': {'kafka': 1}}
2   3                             {'test': {'spark': 2}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nguyễn Huy Hoàng, I am looking for shortcut. I can always fallback to looping

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get exact what I was looking for but able to reach nearby solution

```
labelled_df = labelled_df[["id", "type", "application", "number"]].drop_duplicates()

group_df = labelled_df.groupby(['id', 'type'])[['application', 'number']].apply(
        lambda g: [{row[0]: row[1]} for row in g.values.tolist()]).reset_index(name='group1').groupby('id')[
        'type', 'group1'].apply(lambda g: [{row[0]: row[1]} for row in g.values.tolist()]).reset_index(
        name='applications')
```

which resulted in

```
  asset_id  applications
0        1  [{'test': [{'spark': 2}, {'kafka': 1}]}, {'test1': [{'spark': 2}]}]
1        2  [{'test2': [{'kafka': 1}]}]
2        3  [{'test': [{'spark': 2}]}]
```